# Click Flex 4 spark ToggleButton component in code

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I can't found any property in sparks's ToggleButton that allow me to press it from code. I tested  setCurrentState("down") method, but this way button not dispatching click event i think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to manually create a click event and dispatch it to simulate a "click in code".  Conceptually something like this:

```
var clickEvent : MouseEvent = new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.CLICK)
this.myButton.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
```

If this doesn't switch the toggle state, you may have to do so manually, and your original answer has that code.